# How do I stream HostListener events using RxJs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I find plenty of resources on how to bind Angular [HostListeners](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener):

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
handleClick(event: Event) {
     // etc
}
```

but how would I use RxJs instead, to stream it?

```
documentClickedStream = Observable.fromEvent(/* how to bind this? */)
```

Not sure how to bind to create a "click anywhere" stream using the decorator pattern suggested in the Angular docs.

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish? you want some other component in your application to get notified through ngrx whenever click on this component occurs? or?

Comment: Can you point to decorator documentation link please?

Comment: oops, updated question, I really meant just how to handle a click anywhere on Host element with RxJs, not ngrx. I typed too fast.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the easy way is to just use an intermediary subject:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(e:Event) {
      this.clickStream$.next(e);
  }
```

then sub to it like normal

```
  this.clickStream$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(
          // some operators...
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use template ref to get ref of button

It will work since we are targeting document.

```
@ViewChild('btn') btn:ElementRef;
documentClickedStream = Observable.fromEvent(window['document'],'click');
```

Working example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-window

Comment: how do I do this without a button, i.e. the whole HostElement?

Comment: You want to trigger this if you click any where in the dom?

Comment: Did you check document:click inside from event

Comment: I'm not sure I can access document directly since this is a Nativescript project, but I can try it.

Comment: No it wil work bcoz we are trying to select document

Comment: can't use in Nativescript (there is no document). `Can't find variable: document` however, it works in web. That's why I think accessing the HostElement in Angular requires going through the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example.
First you need to import this lines into your component

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/fromEvent';
```

then put this code into your component constructor or into ngOnInit

```
   fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
    })
```

Comment: But this will break ssr rendering. Using @HostListener is safe.
To make Your code working on Angular Universal You should use a DOCUMENT injection token to inject document object from DI and use it instead of global document object.

Comment: Not sure if this will broke the ssr in case of injecting the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to RxJs events using below given code as well, add below given code to ngOnInit event:

```
this.subscribe(fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange'), (e: Event) => {
    console.log('visibilitychange');
    this.getVisibilitychange(true);
});
```